# sqlite3 syntax for regexp in "search and replace"

Tags: sqlite

I can use regexp to list hits from a Sqlite3 db, but what is the syntax for a "search and replace" using regexp.

Answer (score 4):

If you are thinking of using backreferences in the replacement string, that's not possible, AFAIK. You do an UPDATE, as follows:

```
UPDATE foo
   SET bar = <some expr including baz>
 WHERE baz REGEXP <regex>
```

But the assigned expression will have to rely conventional string functions like `replace(...)` and `substr(...)` (or your own [extension functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)). There is no way to invoke groups found by the `REGEXP` operator.

EDIT: Here's a concrete example that interprets numeric stock IDs following the prefix `'STOCK ID: '` in the `item_key` column as stock numbers:

```
UPDATE staff
   SET stock_number = CAST(substr(item_key, 11) AS INTEGER)
 WHERE item_key REGEXP '^STOCK ID: \d+'
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't fully understand the formatting and how it all applies where you have <some expr including baz> and <regex>. Can you annotate the example fully. Thanks

Comment: @JPG: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: +1 for link to extension functions. This is the way to do what the OP wants.